Let $\operatorname{sr}(K)$ be the subgroup rank of $K$. When is $\operatorname{sr}(H)\le\operatorname{sr}(G)$ for $H\le G$?
The Question:

When is $\operatorname{sr}(H)\le\operatorname{sr}(G)$ for (not necessarily abelian) groups $H\le G$ (in general$^{\dagger}$)?

Here $\operatorname{sr}(G)$ is the subgroup rank of a $G$.
The Details:
Define:

$$\operatorname{rank}(G)=\min\{|X|\mid X\subseteq G, \langle X\rangle =G\}.$$
$$\operatorname{sr}(G)=\max_{H\le G}\operatorname{rank}(H).$$

Thoughts:
The $\operatorname{rank}(G)$ facts listed in the Wikipedia page are helpful.  They imply something I know already: $\operatorname{sr}(H)\le\operatorname{sr}(G)$ if $G\twoheadrightarrow H$ (i.e, $H\cong G/N$, some $N$).
My Background:
As you probably know already, I did an MPhil in combinatorial group theory. Thus you may assume familiarity with concepts in the area in your answers. My copies of Magnus et al.'s book and others like it are elsewhere.

$\dagger$: I think it's unlikely there's a complete characterisation.  If there's none, then a list of known cases will suffice, please; I might add the big-list tag if needs be.

Every subgroup of $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. That means that $${\mathrm{rank}(K)\mid K\leq H}\subseteq {\mathrm{rank}(K)\mid K\leq G}.$$ In particular, the maximum of the subset is less than or equal to the maximum of the larger set. What am I missing?

No, I think that covers it, @ArturoMagidin. Thank you.

Would you like to promote that to an answer, @ArturoMagidin, so I can accept it and close the question?

Since
$\{\mathrm{rank}(K)\mid K\leq H\}\subseteq\{\mathrm{rank}(K)\mid K\leq G\}$, the maximum rank of subgroups of $H$ is necessarily less than or equal to the maximum rank of subgroups of $G$. This immediately yields $\mathrm{sr}(H)\leq\mathrm{sr}(G)$.
